# Can I merge Bootstrap 2.3.1 with new versions like 4.0 or 3.x.x?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I have a website in that I used bootstrap 2.3.1. Now I want to change the version and I want to update. If I updated the bootstrap with new version.
Total UI is changing. **Website turning into clumsy**. So my intention is to just merge the previous bootstrap file with new one without removing the previous attributes and just updating the new content.

Comment: No. You shouldn't be doing that at all.

Comment: Why . Can I replace with new things

Comment: Can confirm. Don't do that. You can try to migrate if your project is small, but merging will cause hardly maintainable mess.

Comment: I want to use new things like panel etc..

Comment: If your project is big, you could try to use new bootstrap on new views or rewrite old views using new bootstrap, while old views would be untouched using old bootstrap. Notice how you don't merge both bootstraps, but still use the new one.

Comment: Can anyone give the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you probably don't want to do it. Merging both Bootstraps will likely cause hardly maintainable mess and conflicts (one behavior overwriting another). But surely it's doable, just a couple more imports of new Bootstrap and there you have it.

I would try solve this without merging different Bootstraps, though! Here's how:

If your project is small, maybe it's good idea to migrate to new Bootstrap and get rid of the old one.

If your project is big, then you could use new Bootstrap in new views, while leaving old views that use old Bootstrap untouched. Then if you have time and resources, you could rewrite/migrate these old views one by one using new Bootstrap. The idea is to not to use both Bootstraps on the same view at the same time, but rather switch to new Bootstrap only for chosen views.

Good luck!